# Matter-js - How to get width and height of rectangle?

Tags: matter.js

Matter-js - How to get width and height of rectangle ?

I need to know is there distance return method implemented in Matter-js .

```
// part.vertices[0] and part.vertices[1]
```

I wanna integrate tiles option.
This is how looks critical part (i use override function for Render.bodies it is most interest for me) .:

```
  for (let x = 0; x < this.tiles; x++) {

    c.drawImage(
      texture,
      texture.width * -part.render.sprite.xOffset * part.render.sprite.xScale,
      texture.height * -part.render.sprite.yOffset * part.render.sprite.yScale,
      texture.width * part.render.sprite.xScale,
      texture.height * part.render.sprite.yScale);

  }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`const { min, max } = part.bounds`

it will contain what you need in `{ x, y }`

just substract `max.x - min.x` & `max.y - min.y`

Comment: FYI this is the boundary rectangle, meaning that if the rectangle is rotated at all then you're getting the width of the boundary, not the rectangle.

Comment: has someone found a solution that will allow rotation

Comment: use https://npmjs.org/package/detect-collisions/ @DavidClews

Answer (score 6):

I went with a solution very similar to the following:

```
var width = 30;
var height = 30;
var rect = Bodies.rectangle(150, 100, width, height, {density:0.01, className:"brick", width:width, height:height});

console.log(rect.className, rect.width); // "brick", 30
```

I decided to carry the original width/height information along with other custom properties such as `className`

The reason why is because `bounds` is affected by the rotation of any non perfectly-circular object eg. a rotated rectangle's bounds could be up to ~30% wider than it's actual width.

Comment: In Typescript you can use <any> for 5th parameter of Bodies.rectangle: `Bodies.rectangle(150, 100, width, height, <any>{density:0.01, className:"brick", width:width, height:height});` to avoid typing errors.

Comment: Yes but in that time i was in wrong opinion. I didnt know that input is already diametric response. I put () {return canvas.innerWidth/100 * percent}  
instead of simple numbers. Bonus problem was scaling... Than i realise "matter inside already handle all positional bugs for resize moment"

Answer (score 3):

There are two solutions that I've found.

1- Create a class to wrap the matter.js body, which will also hold onto the height and width.  ie:

```
class rectWrapper {
  constructor(x, y, width, height, options){
    this.width = width
    this.height = height
    this.body = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(x, y, width, height, options)
    }
}
```

2- Another way is to use the magic of math to determine the distance between two coordinate points, using Body.vertices[0] and Body.vertices[1] for the width, and Body.vertices[0] and Body.vertices[3] for height.  This would also account for any rotation.  This link explains it clearly, for 2 and 3 dimensions:

https://sciencing.com/calculate-distance-between-two-coordinates-6390158.html

I would recommend writing your own "utility function" to do this.  A heavy handed example might look like this:

```
function distance(x1, y1, x2, y2){
  var x = Math.abs(x1-x2)
  var y = Math.abs(y1-y2)
  return Math.sqrt((x*x)+(y*y))
}
```

So a call might look like:

```
var rect = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(0,0,10,50)

var width = distance(rect.vertices[0].x, rect.verticies[0].y, rect.vertices[1].x, rect.vertices[1].y)

var height = distance(rect.vertices[0].x, rect.vertices[0].y, rect.vertices[3].x, rect.vertices[3].y)
```

Alternatively, if you happen to be using p5.js as your renderer, you can use p5.dist() which takes x1, y1, x2, y2 as arguments and returns the distance (basically the same as the function above):

https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/dist

Note, this will only work for rectangles.  If you're using different kinds of geometry, I would probably just make a wrapper class myself.

Comment: `class rectWrapper` nice aproach! Welcome to community

Comment: Thanks!  This is my first answer =)